# iOS simple view for "about us" (or similar) text

Tags: ios, text, uiviewcontroller, text-formatting

I guess I have the simplest problem ever, but can't figure out a nice and clean solution to solve it. Basically I would like to have a simple view, nothing fancy, that shows some infos, a sort of "about us" page.

I've thought of using [UICoreTextView](https://github.com/giladno/UICoreTextView), but it is a bit slow. And, more importantly, I would like to find a more elegant solution, I don't like the idea of having a parsed html page in the app.

The problem, though, is that I haven't found anything useful around, not even some design concepts (which would have been great) or anything. So I was hoping for good ideas/suggestions!

Comment: If you want styled text then UICoreTextView or DTCoreText are good solutions.

Comment: Don't attributed strings work for what you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a UIWebView to display a local HTML file that contains your information?